# How to use Boost Variant with struct objects C++

Tags: c++, boost, struct, conditional-statements, boost-variant

I have two classes and depending on the nature of `key`, I would like to get the struct value out of the `boost::variant`. The code is listed below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    struct greeting {
        string hello;
};


class B {
    public:
    struct greeting {
        string bye;
    };
};

typedef boost::variant<A::greeting, B::greeting> greet;

greet getG(string key) {
    greet g;
    if (key == "A") {
        g.hello = "MY ENEMY"; // this line doesn't work
    }
    else {
        g.bye = "MY FRIEND"; // nor this line
    }
    return g;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    greet h = getG("A");
    A::greeting my = boost::get<A::greeting>(h);
    cout << my.hello << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The exact error that I am getting is: 
`error: no member named 'hello' in 'boost::variant<A::greeting, B::greeting, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, ...>' g.hello = "MY ENEMY";` and
`error: no member named 'bye' in 'boost::variant<A::greeting, B::greeting, .../>' g.bye = "MY FRIEND";`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While line-numbers makes it easy to find specific lines, it also makes it very hard for us to copy the code and try it ourselves. A comment marking out the lines where the errors are is sufficient.

Comment: As for your problem, use [`boost::get`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/get_idp1003723808.html) to get a reference to the specific structure. (See the [Boost variant tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html) for an example on how to use it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variant type doesn't have the `.hello` and `.bye` members. You can access them via a "visitor" function. But you still have to decide what to do when the visitor is not applied to the right type. I think you are not using Boost.Variant in the way that is intended to be used. (For example the conditionals don't smell well).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#variant.concepts.static-visitor

```
struct hello_visitor : boost::static_visitor<>{
    string const& msg;
    hello_visitor(string const& msg) : msg(msg){}
    void operator()(A::greeting& t) const{
        t.hello = msg;
    }
    void operator()(B::greeting& t) const{
        // throw? ignore? other?
    }
};

struct bye_visitor : boost::static_visitor<>{
    string const& msg;
    bye_visitor(string const& msg) : msg(msg){}
    void operator()(A::greeting& t) const{
        // throw? ignore? other?
    }
    void operator()(B::greeting& t) const{
        t.bye = msg;
    }
};


greet getG(string key) {
    greet g;
    if (key == "A") { // is "key" handling the type, if so you can delegate this to the library instead of doing this.
        boost::apply_visitor(hello_visitor("MY ENEMY"), g); 
    }
    else {
        boost::apply_visitor(bye_visitor("MY FRIEND"), g); 
    }
    return g;
};
```

Comment: I just removed the line numbers. I tested out the code and I got `error: no matching function for call to bye_visitor` and `hello_visitor`. Do you mind pointing me out what I am missing?

Comment: This code works now. It is not completely clear what you want to do. Looks like you are mixing some manual variant (with your conditionals) with the actual Boost.Variant. The idea of Boost.Variant is that you don't have to deal with the "real-type" decision tree.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.